# Hide NSUserNotification after certain time

Tags: cocoa, notifications, swift2

Currently when i create a NSUserNotification using Alert style it won't hide unless i manually close it.

[image]

Is there a way i can auto close/hide it say after 2 sec?

NSUserNotification code is for reference :

```
let notification:NSUserNotification = NSUserNotification()
notification.title = "Title"
notification.subtitle = "Subtitle"
notification.informativeText = "Informative text"

notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName

notification.deliveryDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)
notification.hasActionButton = false
let notificationcenter:NSUserNotificationCenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()
notificationcenter.scheduleNotification(notification)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually very simple to do this, using NSObject's 
`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method.

Because you're scheduling the notification delivery after a certain time interval, you need to add the additional delay before dismissing, to the initial delay before delivering. Here, I've written them out as constants of 10 seconds before delivery, and 2 seconds before dismissal:

```
let delayBeforeDelivering: NSTimeInterval = 10
let delayBeforeDismissing: NSTimeInterval = 2

let notification = NSUserNotification()
notification.title = "Title"
notification.deliveryDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: delayBeforeDelivering)

let notificationcenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter()

notificationcenter.scheduleNotification(notification)

notificationcenter.performSelector("removeDeliveredNotification:",
    withObject: notification,
    afterDelay: (delayBeforeDelivering + delayBeforeDismissing))
```

And for Swift 5 you can use the following:

```
let delayBeforeDelivering: TimeInterval = 10
let delayBeforeDismissing: TimeInterval = 2

let notification = NSUserNotification()
notification.title = "Title"
notification.deliveryDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: delayBeforeDelivering)

let notificationcenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.default

notificationcenter.scheduleNotification(notification)

notificationcenter.perform(#selector(NSUserNotificationCenter.removeDeliveredNotification(_:)),
                with: notification,
                afterDelay: (delayBeforeDelivering + delayBeforeDismissing))
```

Comment: What if you want to leave it in the notification center though? (Just remove the popup) is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `removeDeliveredNotification`: or `removeAllDeliveredNotifications` with timer

```
// Clear a delivered notification from the notification center. If the notification is not in the delivered list, nothing happens.
- (void)removeDeliveredNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification;

// Clear all delivered notifications for this application from the notification center.
- (void)removeAllDeliveredNotifications;
```

OS X (10.8 and later)

Comment: Hi Parag, thanks for this. So i tried using this but unfortunately it won't work. Here is my code which i added after my previous code. 
        let seconds = 15.0
        let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
        let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            
            var test = NSUserNotificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications(notificationcenter)
            print(test)
        })

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote Is there a way i can auto close/hide it say after 2 sec?

No, you do not have any such option till OSX 10.11, may be in future Apple may provide.

There are three ways a user can customise the `NSUserNotification` also known as Growl notification:

1. None
2. Banner
3. Alert

You as a developer can not control over the system settings. This is upto the user to enable or disable and choose what kind of notification he likes.

If you want any alert to be shown to user you can create your own alert window and show it in that corner. You can set a timer to close, or provide action button to close it once you need.

**Update 1:**
Cocoa provides `NSWindow` & `NSPanel`(HUD and normal panel). You can either customize Window or panel according to your need. Check there are multiple options that would help you to form as per your requirement.

If you can't get, say you wanted a rounded corner then you need to customize the window/view etc.

Comment: Hi Anoop, Thanks for your reply. You suggested for using custom alert window? Can you suggest what api i should look at for this? I was looking into the new MS outlook 2016 app, it implemented some kind of alert which looks exactly like the default but is not the default one. It also hides automatically. So may be even it uses similar approach